# Bootstrap modal inside iframe wont animate into viewport of iframe

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, scroll, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal inside an iframe.  If I scroll down within the iframe and execute the modal I cant see it because its at the top of the iframe where I have to scroll up to see it.  Is there a way to have it stay within the viewport of the iframe?

Comment: Can you provide a mockup of your problem, or at least the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Provided you'll always be scrolling to the bottom of the iframe to click the button that launches it, you can use a bit of CSS to push it more towards the bottom of the page/frame.

**[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/PGj6ou8Gps)**

**CSS:**

```
.modal {
    top: 50%;
  }
```

The code for the modal is just the boilerplate code you'll find for modals in the Bootstrap documentation. I simply applied the CSS to the modal class.

Comment: Wont this just center the modal within the window not viewport?

Comment: Doesn't look like it: http://jsbin.com/zatehofipo/1/edit?html,css,js,output. That's a JS Bin with another JS Bin in an iframe. The modal is pushed down in the iframe itself.

Comment: Updated JS Bin, hopefully one that won't expire. Same concept as the one above. http://jsbin.com/biqugu/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Sorry I am not scrolling to the bottom of the iframe and this doesnt work.  It centers it within the iframe, not the viewport where you can see it or where you clicked the button on the page.

Comment: Your question literally states that you, "Have a bootstrap modal inside an iframe," and you're wondering why it stays within the iframe and doesn't enter the entire viewport? Maybe you should provide a visual example of your problem, or some actual code if you want people to have a better understanding of what you're talking about. You launch a modal that's part of a page inside the iframe, of course it's going to pop at the top of the frame and not the entire viewport for your whole page.

Comment: I also don't feel it's appropriate to downvote an answer that's trying to help solve a problem where the asker hasn't provided the required items SO says they need to provide in order to receive an answer.

Comment: The viewport of the IFRAME, not the page.

Comment: Right, modal pops inside the iframe, it's going to pop at the top of the page being displayed in the iframe, and if you've scrolled to the bottom of the page then you won't see the modal. That's how I'm reading your question, and as such what you need is a way to push that modal to the bottom of the page so when it pops due to the user clicking a button, they actually see the modal in the iframe and don't have to scroll up.

Comment: Exactly doing a 50% top of the modal only centers it in the middle of the iframe still hidden from the iframe viewport where I still have to scroll to see it.  This is a long page so I just dont see how 50% top works.

Comment: Yeah, and your point is? Is that not low enough? Does the modal need to pop somewhere else, like outside the iframe? You're seriously not providing the information needed to get you the answer you need, via the problem code, and/or a visual representation of the problem. I seriously do not see how I'm not answering your question, which contains none of the parts SO says you need to provide to even receive an answer in the first place.

Comment: @MikeFlynn Oh my word, the problem is the page is so long that setting top to 50% doesn't work? Maaaaaaybe try **increasing the number for your specific page then**? You provided no code and no context, so I'm taking a stab in the dark here man. How do I know how long your page is or that 50% won't work? Further, how could you not figure out that increasing the percentage would get the modal to come down even more if the page is really long?

Comment: There are a number of buttons on the page so this one stop solution is the problem. It has to be a generic solution.

Comment: So then you can probably write a bit of JS/jQuery to set the top value of the modal depending on where the button is? That said, either put up code/a mockup and possibly an image of the page you're dealing with, because I'm not wasting my time on this anymore. You have nearly 5k rep on this site, you should know what's required to get the proper answers you seek.

Comment: I dont have any code to provide since there are a number of things in place and code will NOT help.  This either can work or not work.  Im not sure where you even got I was at the bottom of the page, it looked like you just assumed right off the bat.  Ask a question under the question first before assuming and posting an answer.  I would delete this entirely.

Comment: Two people found it helpful, so I'm not sure I want to. Regardless, you need to provide code or some kind of material to show what you've done to try and solve the problem, and you haven't. I'm simply trying to help, or at least set you in the right direction. Were I to have more context into your problem, such as how many buttons/page length/other factors, I could likely work up a more complete solution. As it stands, though, you've failed to do that, so I'm simply not going to waste my time on it anymore. When you give no context, you leave lots of room for assumption. Best of luck.